# Has my hard drive arrived faulty?

Tags: hard-drive, clicking-sound

I got a 1TB Western Digital Blue hard drive, and it is not recognized by my BIOS or Windows installation.

BIOS shows hard drive is placed in SATA slot, but no serial number, model number, or capacity is shown. The same is for the Windows installation. The partition and format buttons in the Windows setup are grayed out too.

Also, my hard drive makes clicking noises for about 15 seconds every 30 - 60 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, the clicking usually indicates a dead drive.

Comment: If you plug it in all cables connections are secure then the drive is dead

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a problem with the read/write head, which usually means that the drive is dead or about to die. You should return the drive.

Quote from [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Problem_with_hard_drive_clicking):

> The click sound is usually caused by the drive parking its head. There
>   are multiple causes for that, including power management and shock
>   detection. However, it may also mean that your
>   drive is about to die.

Answer (score 2):

yes , your HDD is faulty.You may want to replace it / return to the store.

[Click of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death) is a term that became common in the late 1990s referring to the clicking sound in disk storage systems that signals a disk drive has failed, often catastrophically.

The clicking sound itself arises from the unexpected movement of the disk's read-write actuator.