# Is my new hard drive probably mechanically broken?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I bought 2 hard drives of the same model. I am trying to use them on a laptop with Linux 4.10.11-1-ARCH installed via a USB dock. The first drive works fine. The second one, I cannot even partition. Here is what the kernel log says when it is plugged in:

```
[57059.401021] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[57059.545858] scsi host7: uas
[57068.811877] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access                               0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[57068.868569] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[57068.870869] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[57068.871372] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[57068.871376] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[57068.872115] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[57068.876510] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

For comparison, here is the log when the other, functional hard drive is plugged in:

```
[57628.084298] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
[57628.242187] scsi host7: uas
[57628.250225] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD16 00AAJS-75M0A0    0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[57628.288450] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[57628.290074] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 312500000 512-byte logical blocks: (160 GB/149 GiB)
[57628.290584] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[57628.290588] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[57628.292703] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[57628.356484]  sdc: sdc1
[57628.362829] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

Also, the non-functional drive makes 5 pairs of clicks when it is attached that the functional drive does not make. Is that likely the [click of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death)  or might there be some way to get the non-functional drive to work using software?
I'm guessing my situation is the same a this person who asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/651508/has-my-hard-drive-arrived-faulty), but I would like to have that guess confirmed by someone with more experience before I give up on the drive.

More details:

The USB drive dock has it's own power supply. It is a Plugable USB 3.1 Gen 2 10Gbps SATA Upright Hard Drive Dock and SSD Dock.

Output of "smartctl -a /dev/sdc" on the non-functional disk:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.10.11-1-ARCH] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     [No Information Found]
Serial Number:    [No Information Found]
Firmware Version: [No Information Found]
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   [No Information Found]
Local Time is:    Sat May 13 12:14:51 2017 EDT
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 82-83 don't show if SMART supported.
SMART support is: Ambiguous - ATA IDENTIFY DEVICE words 85-87 don't show if SMART is enabled.
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

Comment: I would suggest testing with an internal SATA port if you have one available, as USB adapters can be iffy at times. Otherwise, request a replacement under warranty.

Comment: No smartctl information indicates a communication error (USB-to-SATA bridge doesn't work) or failure of harddisk microcontroller. It says nothing about the harddrive itself being mechanically broken. As the other comment says, test directly with ATA to see if the USB-to-SATA bridge is the problem.

Comment: @Bob (and dirkt) thanks for your feedback. I will test on an internal SATA port next week.

Comment: For the record, the drive behaved the same when attached to an internal SATA port, so I'm returning it.